# Get real value or None from a HashMap

Tags: rust

I have a `struct` that I would like to fill based on a potentially incomplete hash map:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Sue {
    children: Option<u8>,
    cats: Option<u8>,
    samoyeds: Option<u8>,
    pomeranians: Option<u8>,
    akitas: Option<u8>,
    vizslas: Option<u8>,
    goldfish: Option<u8>,
    trees: Option<u8>,
    cars: Option<u8>,
    perfumes: Option<u8>,
}

impl Sue {
    fn from_line(line: &str) -> Sue {
        let data: Vec<&str> = line.split(" ").collect();

        let items: HashMap<String, u8> = data[2..data.len()]
            .chunks(2)
            .map(|item| {
                (
                    String::from(item[0].trim_end_matches(":")),
                    String::from(item[1].trim_end_matches(",")).parse().unwrap(),
                )
            })
            .collect();

        println!("{:?}\n", items);

        Sue {
            // children: match items.get("children"){
                // Some(val) => Some(*val),
                // None => None,
            // },
            children: *items.get("children"),
            // cats: Some(0),
            // samoyeds: Some(0),
            // pomeranians: Some(0),
            // akitas: Some(0),
            // vizslas: Some(0),
            // goldfish: Some(0),
            // trees: Some(0),
            // cars: Some(0),
            // perfumes: Some(0),
        }
    }
}
```

In the snippet above, the `items` hash map may or may not contain a key for each field of the `Sue` struct. My idea was to build a hash map with the input, and then for each field of the struct, try to access the corresponding key of the hashmap. If the key is in the hashmap, return the dereferenced value. If the key isn't in the hashmap, return None.

I know I can do that with a match (there is a couple of lines commented showing how I would do this), but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this (it's a lot of boilerplate; one match for each field).

If I run the code above, I'll get:

```
error[E0614]: type `Option<&u8>` cannot be dereferenced
```

Any idea? I do want to keep None if the key isn't found. Also for reference, this snippet is for advent of code 2015 day 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`copied`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.copied) or [`cloned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.cloned) to convert an `Option<&T>` to `Option<T>`. The first is available if `T: Copy`, the second if `T: Clone`.

`u8` implements both so you can use either method.

```
children: items.get("children").copied(),
```

Comment: Ah, I tried `clone` but it wasn't working. Thanks, I'll accept the answer.  More generally, do you see a better approach than the one I'm using? In Python I could just unpack the hash map and pass it to the init of the struct and default the missing keys. I could even inspect the fields of the data structure and make the code more generic.

Comment: Are you deserializing data? Perhaps there's a [crate](https://crates.io/keywords/serialization) that could help, such as [serde](https://serde.rs/).

Answer (score 0):

For `u8`, either of the methods John Kugelman mentioned work great. However, there are some types that are neither `Copy` nor cheaply cloneable (maybe they don't implement `Clone` at all, or they do but it is costly).

A third option is to remove the item from the map:

```rust
struct ExpensiveClone(u8);

impl Clone for ExpensiveClone {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
        Self(self.0)
    }
}
```

In this case, cloning would likely be prohibitively expensive. Instead, if you have owned or mutable access to the map, you can remove it, transferring ownership of the value from the map to your function, without needing to clone the data:

```rust
let mut map = HashMap::new();
map.insert(1, ExpensiveClone(1));
let expensive_clone = map.remove(&1).unwrap();
assert_eq!(expensive_clone.0, 1);
```

It goes without saying that this only works if you can modify the map though